Filtering a Table for a date range that exists in two date columns
I am fairly fresh here so please forgive me if this has been asked previously. I have a data model in MS PowerBI which has a date table and a fact table with two date columns (ME_PostDate, ME_Rec_Date, note ME = month end). There is an active relationship between the ME_PostDate and Date_Table and an Inactive relationship between ME_Rec_Date and Date _Table.
I have calculated a measure to calculate the sum of a column (J Profit) where both ME_PostDate and ME_Rec_Date are the same. The measure used is JP_PDRD_Month =
CALCULATE(Sum(a_NZ_JPR\[J Profit NZD\]),a_NZ_JPR\[ME_PostDate\] = a_NZ_JPR\[ME_Rec_Date\])

This is seems to work fine.
The issue is that I need to calculate a measure where for a range of dates (i.e. the year to date) where this works.
Note applying a TOTALYTD or a DATESBETWEEN on JP_PDRD_Month seems to return the case where all month end dates are the same for each period and then aggregating these.
What I am hoping to find a solution to is where a date range for both these columns (i.e ME_Recog_Date is between 31/7/2024 and 31/8/2024 AND ME_Post_Date is between 31/7/2024 and 31/8/2024) is true.
Please see below for screen shots and a table.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.





ID
ME_Rec_Date
ME_PostDate
JobProfit
RD=PD
RangePD=RD




0
7
6
15




1
6
7
10




2
7
7
30
1
1


3
7
7
15
1
1


4
8
7
25

1


5
6
7
35




6
7
8
25

1


7
7
8
45

1


8
8
8
15
1
1


9
8
8
10
1
1


10
9
8
20




11
8
9
30





Sum where months are the same for each month = $70 (i.e. PD=RD is 1)
What I am hoping to find a PowerBi measure (DAX) solution for is where total date range (31/7/2024 <--> 31/8/2024) is the same for both columns. i.e. = $165 (i.e. Range PD=RD is 1)
For the above the excel fx is =SUMIFS(Demo\[JobProfit\],Demo\[ME_Rec_Date\],"\>="&7,Demo\[ME_Rec_Date\],"\<="&8,Demo\[ME_PostDate\],"\>="&7,Demo\[ME_PostDate\],"\<="&8)
Greatly appreciated,
Dave
I tried the using the following formulas DatesYTD, Datebetween, Calculate, Userrelationship. I can apply a filter by the activerelationship ME_Post_Date : Date_Tble[Date] but haven't been succesful in applying are date range to both the date columns in the fact table


You can approach this by first getting a list of IDs for one of the date columns, then for the second date column, use the list of IDs to filter on.
For example:
Example = 
  var recogIDs =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT(a_NS_JPR[ID]),
      USERELATIONSHIP(Date_Table[Date], a_NS_JPR[ME_Recog_Date])
    )
  var result = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM(a_NS_JPR[Job Profit]),
      a_NS_JPR[ID] IN recogIDs
    )
  RETURN result


From here you can use the above as a base measure for Time Intelligence measures. For example:
Example YTD = 
  CALCULATE(
    [Example],
    DATESYTD(Date_Table[Date])
  )


Hi Sam, Thanks for this code i have applied it and it works a charm.
I am wanting the measure to be a year to date calculation so that what ever the selected month end is selected, the measure calculates the year to date to that period.
That is (screen shot added in original post) 8.67 when month Aug-24 is selected. As opposed  to select all the months Jan --> Aug in the slicer.
I have tried wrapping the measure in a TotalYTD function but it doesn't make any difference to the outcome.
Much appreciated. Cheers Dave

Since the above measure is already doing the "SUM" or Total, you would need to wrap it in DATESYTD. Eg: Example YTD = CALCULATE([Example], DATESYTD(Date_Table[Date])). Added to the answer above.

Thanks for this Sam I have wrapped this in a calculate function and it is doing what it needs to. There is one thing which is problematic
The DatesYTD runs forward to future dated jobs and the report needs to show values based on the selected slicer, so I have added a DATESBETWEEN in the filter argument. eg:
CALCULATE([Example_YTD],DATESBETWEEN(Date_Table[Date],"01/01/2024","31/8/2024"))
